# JMS Serializer deserialize ArrayCollection of Objects

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.3

I have serialized ArrayCollection with Objects, everything is serialized into json with jms/serializer-bundle.

When I want deserialize my collection with keys (it's important):

```
deserialize($data, 'ArrayCollection<int, FooBundle\Entity\Item>', 'json');
```

I get array. But when I make new ArrayCollection with results:

```
new ArrayCollection(deserialize($data, 'ArrayCollection<int, FooBundle\Entity\Item>', 'json'));
```

Everything is fine and I get ArrayCollection with Objects and all keys are kept. Maybe someone knows why 1st method doesn't work?

Jms serializer has possibility to deserialize into ArrayCOllection f Objects section @Type here: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution that I found was creating separate class with items (ArrayCollection type) field. Here is jms-serializer definition for this class:

```
FooBundle\Entity\Cart:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        items:
            expose: true
            type: ArrayCollection<int, FooBundle\Entity\CartItem>
```